# Updates to the site

Tags: discussion, design

You may have noticed some updates to the design lately, they are part of a SE network-wide update to a new base css framework.

The updates allow us to:

- Have sharper / more beautiful design on retina displays
- Fix layout bugs
- More easily add new features to all of our sites in the future

As you can see, the layout of the header section was also updated for a better use of the space while using our new Q/A site design layout.

> **But more importantly, it gives you access [to the new profile](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/current)!**

If you see any bugs please let us know in the form of answers (to this post) that illustrate one particular thing at a time.

Thanks!

Comment: YAY! I've been waiting for this since I saw it on SO.

Comment: Is there an ETA for when this is going to go live?

Comment: Updated question - Is there an ETA of _less than_ 6 to 8 weeks for when the changes will go live?

Comment: @GlenH7 It's hard to know exactly when it'll go live as we work on several projects at once, but we'll do our best!

Comment: @StéphaneMartin just trying to manage my own expectations for this... do you think it would be done before or after the featured tag auto-removes itself in (IIRC) three weeks?

Comment: Still no sign of the update. What's happening here?

Comment: The update has been delayed a bit due to some (awesome?) new projects we're currently working on. But I'll do my best to do it asap.

Comment: Ugh, what? The design itself is pretty public currently, why not roll it out as-is? As far I can see, it doesn't have really many bugs...

Comment: The logo is broken. Why does it go `/* Programmers *\\`? That's not how comments work...

Comment: @ThomasOwens My bad, fixed, pushed :)

Comment: Do you have the old logo and vote/fav icons for a side-by-side reference? It currently looks *wrong*, but without the old one to compare it's hard to say if it's really worse, or if I'm simply not used to the new version/

Comment: I didn't change the favicon @CodesInChaos, and regarding the vote icons, they're now sharper & retina, so you can see more details

Comment: @StéphaneMartin I was referring to the fav star below the vote icons.

Answer (score 14):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Thanks for the catch, it's now fixed and will be live after our next production build.

---

You've got a 'bug' in the title.

[image]

That *should* be a forward slash on the end. `/* Programmers */` is correct.

Answer (score 3):

The location of the text shifts depending on which question category is selected.

> [image]
>
> [image]

Notice that the 'T' in the first one lines up to the red arrow in the background image differently in each image.

The browser in use there is IE 10.

Answer (score 2):

So, my profile top looks like this:

> [image]

After mousing over various parts it looks like (without the freehand red <s>hot dogs</s> circles):

> [image]

These areas do not re-collapse.

The browser in use is IE 10.

Answer (score 2):

Not a bug per se but the non-flat, rounded buttons for submitting answers looks weird compared to the rest of the design which is flat and square.

[image: non-flat button]

Answer (score 2):

I noticed a very minor UI glitch in my Programmers profile.

Notice how the *See votes, expandable usercard* privilege name touches the close button.

This is a really minor issue but it's annoying given how much work has been done on the neat redesign recently ;)

My browser is *Chrome 43.0.2357.124 m*, I'm using *Windows 8.1 Enterprise*

[image: Lack of padding between the text and close button]

I cannot reproduce this in *Firefox 38.0.5* on the same machine. The text wraps into the next line there.

[image: Same box in Firefox, working properly]